# How to use an existing Java Type Renderer for a Java Type Renderer in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ / Customize Data Views, I have defined a Java Type Renderer "Pair":
[image]

As you can see, I display the value as expression `"left: " + this.left + ", right: " + this.right`. This basically works, but I want the field `this.right` (which is in this case formatted using the object's `toString()`-method) also to be rendered using the corresponding Java Type Renderer, if there is one defined for the object type.

---

Example:

```
Pair pair = new Pair("key", new Pair("innerKey", "innerValue"));
```

In IntelliJ debugger, this object is rendered like this: `left: key, right: at.tac.ra.utils.datastructures.Pair@a5b7d62`
But I want it to be rendered like this: `left: key, right: Pair{left: innerKey, right: innerValue}`

---

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I guess you might want to deselect the `Show type and id` checkbox on the rendering node options and for expanded nodes define the same expression, though haven't tried that feature in IntelliJ yet TBH.

Comment: The `Show type and object id` checkbox does not affect this. I tried to define the same expression for expanded nodes, but that does not make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet possible, please vote https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170893

Comment: Thank you for that answer. One more question: How can I vote for that issue?

Comment: There's a thumb up button near the "voters" on the right side of the page. Probably you need to be registered to vote.